# Xcode/Interface Builder crash

Tags: xcode, crash

Iam using Xcode 4.4 on Mountain Lion and unable to do any IB related tasks.
Dragging a control to a xib file, connecting an IBoutlet to code, whatever I do , Xcode crashes
Any clues will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation sounds remarkably similar to what happened to me yesterday:

[Xcode Interface Builder crashes when I edit storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580881/xcode-interface-builder-crashes-when-i-edit-storyboard)

It would be worth looking at the console log to see if the reports are the same. If they are, experiment with the 'Use auto layout' checkbox.